Laravel App Working on HTTP but Not on HTTPS (403 Error)
My Laravel application functions properly with HTTP URL but having an issue with HTTPS, displaying the error message Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
kindly review this image and provide guidance on resolving this issue?
HTTPS response image
HTTPS/SSL is already configured. Both URL versions are working, but only the HTTP URL version is showing me data. The HTTPS version is displaying this error message in console and showing blank page: 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()'.
SSL Configured image
Laravel .env inside configuration
APP_NAME='TradeWithShine Exchange'
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=base64:PqJTkxOD1loJIUnMtvkhmKLYTa/NFbsJtkQR0dxaQx8=
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_URL=https://coinspay.xyz
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS="coinspay.xyz"
LOG_CHANNEL=stack
TRADE_FREQUENCY=10

USER_ASSETS="false"
USER_ASSETS_HASH="1708829973402"

OS: Ubuntu 22.04 Hosting Panel: aaPanel Web Server: Nginx
I've done changes in NGINX Config file. Please check.
user  www www;
worker_processes auto;
error_log  /www/wwwlogs/nginx_error.log  crit;
pid        /www/server/nginx/logs/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 51200;

stream {
    log_format tcp_format '$time_local|$remote_addr|$protocol|$status|$bytes_sent|$bytes_received|$session_time|$upstream_addr|$upstream_bytes_sent|$upstream_bytes_received|$upstream_connect_time';
  
    access_log /www/wwwlogs/tcp-access.log tcp_format;
    error_log /www/wwwlogs/tcp-error.log;
    include /www/server/panel/vhost/nginx/tcp/*.conf;
}

events {
    use epoll;
    worker_connections 51200;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
    fastcgi_cache_path /dev/shm/nginx-cache/wp levels=1:2 keys_zone=WORDPRESS:100m inactive=60m max_size=1g;
    fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_500;
    fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
 
    include       mime.types;
    include proxy.conf;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 512;
    client_header_buffer_size 32k;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;
    client_max_body_size 50m;
    sendfile   on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    keepalive_timeout 60;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 64k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 64k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 128k;
    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length  1k;
    gzip_buffers     4 16k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_types     text/plain application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text/css application/xml application/json image/jpeg image/gif image/png font/ttf font/otf image/svg+xml application/xml+rss text/x-js;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied   expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_disable   "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=perip:10m;
    limit_conn_zone $server_name zone=perserver:10m;
    server_tokens off;
    access_log off;

    server {
        listen 888;
        server_name phpmyadmin;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        root  /www/server/phpmyadmin;
        location ~ /tmp/ {
            return 403;
        }
        include enable-php.conf;
        location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf)$ {
            expires      30d;
        }
        location ~ .*\.(js|css)?$ {
            expires      12h;
        }
        location ~ /\.
        {
            deny all;
        }
        access_log  /www/wwwlogs/access.log;
    }

    # Add your server block configurations here
    server {
        listen 80;
        root /www/wwwroot/coinspay.xyz/public;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        server_name coinspay.xyz;
        client_max_body_size 80M;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$query_string;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

        error_page 404 /index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php-cgi-81.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }

        location /socket.io {
            proxy_pass https://localhost:6001;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }

    include /www/server/panel/vhost/nginx/*.conf;
}


Based on what you've show us here, the SSL is being terminated somewhere other than the nginx server you showed the config for. You've not provided any details to suggest that the request is even arriving at the nginx nor php server.

@symcbean the issue has been resolved now. Thank you for your response. I've added SSL port configuration to my Nginx config file, and now both ports, 80 and 443, are working.
